# Genetic STRUCTURE plot in R wrapping function

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics

I produced a stacked bar plot like this [image] commonly called STRUCTURE that, up to my knowledge, there is no wrapping function to this kind of plot suitable for probabilities in R.

As you can see, it is divided in 2 rows: the first one with different K (aka current and alternative taxonomic hypothesis but I would like to show up to 5 rows with different K), populations (AS,SM,PO, etc)  that belong to different species (top plot, "Specie3+Specie4+Specie5" vs "Specie1","Specie2";bottom "Specie1","Specie2","Specie3","Specie4","Specie5")

This plot has been produced with this code (the ggplot part)

```
#K=number of rows 
#taxa= can be different from population, meaning the gruping of a set of population
#posterior = a probability matrix
#target_class = populations
STRUCTURE <- function(posteriors, target_class, K, taxa) {
  #capture errors 
  if (!requireNamespace("tidyverse", quietly = TRUE)) {
    stop("The 'tidyverse' package is required. Please install and load it before using this function.")
  }
  library(tidyverse)
  
  if (!requireNamespace("ggthemes", quietly = TRUE)) {
    stop("The 'ggthemes' package is required. Please install and load it before using this function.")
  }
  library(ggthemes)
  
  if (!requireNamespace("ggforce", quietly = TRUE)) {
    stop("The 'ggforce' package is required. Please install and load it before using this function.")
  }
  library(ggforce)
  
  if (!requireNamespace("RColorBrewer", quietly = TRUE)) {
    stop("The 'RColorBrewer' package is required. Please install and load it before using this function.")
  }
  library(RColorBrewer)
  
  if (is.null(posteriors) || is.null(target_class) || length(posteriors) == 0 || length(target_class) == 0) {
    stop("Both 'posteriors' and 'target_class' must contain non-empty data.")
  } #### checking if all arguments contain data
  
  if (!is.data.frame(posteriors)) { 
    if (is.list(posteriors) && "z" %in% names(posteriors)) {
      posteriors <- as.data.frame(posteriors$z)
    } else {
      warning("Invalid posteriors data. Attempting to coerce into a data frame.")
      posteriors <- as.data.frame(posteriors)
    }
  } else if (ncol(posteriors) != length(levels(factor(target_class)))) {
    stop("Number of levels should be the same!")
  } else {
    ####GENERATE INDEXING #####
    n_per_class <- unname(table(target_class))
    n_of_class <- length(levels(factor(target_class)))
    
    # Define a function to generate the codes
    generate_index <- function(n_per_class, n_of_class) {
      codes <- character(0)  # Initialize an empty character vector
      # Loop through classes
      for (class_index in 1:n_of_class) {
        class_code <- LETTERS[class_index]  # Get class code (A, B, C, ...)
        
        # Get the number of individuals for the current class
        n <- n_per_class[class_index]
        # Loop through individuals within the class
        for (individual_index in 1:n) {
          individual_code <- sprintf("%02d", individual_index)  # Format as two digits (01, 02, 03, ...)
          code <- paste0(class_code, individual_code)  # Combine class and individual code
          codes <- c(codes, code)  # Append to the vector
        }
      }
      return(codes)
    }
    index <- generate_index(n_per_class, n_of_class)
    #apply index, taxonomic_hypothesis and species name to the columns
    
    posteriors$Row <- index
    posteriors$subplot <- K
    posteriors$taxa <- taxa
    
    #gather the data 
    STRUCTURE.data <- gather(posteriors, key = "Column", value = "Value", -Row) ##### <- missing a way to add more than 1 K#### 
    
    # Generate a random color palette 
    selected_colors <- brewer.pal(length(levels(factor(target_class))), "RdYlGn")  ##### <- missing a way to specify colors if default are ugly K#### 
    
    #create the plot 
    STRUCPLOT <- ggplot(STRUCTURE.data, aes(x=Row, y=Value, fill = Column)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill", width = 1) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = selected_colors)+
      facet_grid(subplot ~ fct_inorder(target_class)+taxa, scales = "free", space = "free")+ ##### <- missing a way to write to the bottom the species neams on all subplots #### 
      labs(y = "Posterior probability", x = NULL) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1), expand = c(0, 0)) +
      guides(fill = FALSE) + 
      theme_tufte(base_size = 15, base_family = "sans") +
      theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'transparent'),
            plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'transparent', color = NA),
            legend.background = element_rect(fill = 'transparent'),
            legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = 'transparent'),
            legend.key = element_rect(fill = 'transparent'),
            axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
            axis.text.x = element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),# regulate the size of values of posterirors in y 
            axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15),#regulate the size of "posterior Prob"
            strip.text.x = element_text(size = 8), #regulate the size of pop name
            plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,1,0.5), "cm"),#regulate margin of the whole plot
            panel.spacing = unit(0,'lines'), #regulate margin distance of the facet colums
            panel.spacing.x=unit(0, "lines"),
            panel.spacing.y=unit(2.5, "lines"),
            panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, size = 1))
    
    print(STRUCPLOT)
  }
}
```

However, there are some things that I'm not able to fix...

1. Species should be on the bottom of each rows (I think ggrob should do the trick, labeller didn't work for me )

2)allowing for specify the colors if the user want

3. I don't know how to set the data if multiple K are added..

Any help is deeply appreciated

Some data for a MRE

```
set.seed(123)

#K=1
# Generate some dummy data of random probabilities in a 100x5 matrix 
n_rows <- 100
n_cols <- 5
fake_prob_matrix <- matrix(runif(n_rows * n_cols), nrow = n_rows, ncol = n_cols)
# Normalize the values in each column to sum up to 1
fake_prob_matrix <- data.frame(fake_prob_matrix / rowSums(fake_prob_matrix))
colnames(fake_prob_matrix) <- c("Pop1","Pop2","Pop3","Pop4","Pop5")s
species_k1 <- factor(c("Specie1","Specie2","Specie3","Specie4","Specie5")

#K=2 melting some species to assess cluster purity
n_rows <- 100
n_cols <- 5
fake_prob_matrix <- matrix(runif(n_rows * n_cols), nrow = n_rows, ncol = n_cols)
# Normalize the values in each column to sum up to 1
fake_prob_matrix <- data.frame(fake_prob_matrix / rowSums(fake_prob_matrix))
colnames(fake_prob_matrix) <- c("Pop1","Pop2","Pop3","Pop4","Pop5")
species_k2 <- factor(c("Specie1","Specie2","Specie3+Specie4+Specie5")
```

Thank you!

Comment: Google says someone tried to plot it using R, seven years ago, try it out, in case you haven't already. https://github.com/DrewWham/Genetic-Structure-Tools

Comment: You are right... I'm sorry for haven't found it previously. However, it cannot handle multiple subplots like  
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-37881-0/figures/1